# Prevent apps from closing when phone is locked

Tags: applications, cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s-5

On my Samsung Galaxy S5 (Running CyanogenMod 12.1), when the phone locks apps that are running (both foreground and background) stops, for ex: when I'm downloading a file on UC browser, it automatically closes once the screen is locked (includeing IM apps such as Whatsapp).
I have already checked if any such option is turned on in my RAM cleaner (I use Clean Master) and I also checked if powersaving mode is enabled, both are turned off.

Comment: 1) you don't need any "RAM clearer" apps - Android is doing a far better job managing applications. 2) Have you installed any battery saving app like Greenify or something like that?

Comment: The  ram cleaner has an in-built battery battery saver, but I have checked that too, I have not enabled any such option @benjaminSyesterday

Comment: go to power settings, add needed apps to protected apps. sure it will work